# error handling Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message SWbemLocator. Description: Access is denied

Tags: php, com, wmi

I'm connecting to a remote server to get some WMI information

```
$wmiLocator = new COM('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
$obj = $wmiLocator->ConnectServer($host, 'root\cimv2', $user, $pass);
$Printers =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer");
```

The username and password are entered by the user. I want now to be sure that he entered his credentials correctly before running the query because otherwhise I get the following error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
>   '**Source:** SWbemLocator
> **Description:** Access is denied.
>   ' in test.php

Does someone have an idea how to catch this or how to check for access in beforehand?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to add additional WMI code to authenticate since WMI requires additional creds. I don't know php but if you want to translate from VBS then I can post an answer with some helpful info and links.

Comment: Its more about to catch the error when authentication fails. The code above works when creds are ok.
`$wmiLocator = new COM('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
$obj = $wmiLocator->ConnectServer($host, 'root\cimv2', $user, $pass);
$Printers =    $obj->ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer");   
foreach ( $Printers as $wmi_Printer ) {
$PortName = $wmi_Printer->PortName;
echo $PortName// gives connected printer names;
}`
Where $user and $pass comming from a form.
I'll check with error catching (try())

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? I need to catch the error also when the host is not available or does not respond.